# how to get rid of this char in my csv â€“

Tags: c#, csv, .net-core, encoding

I am using

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Uri.EscapeDataString(propValue.ToString()))
```

and

```
return File(bResult, "application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8",
```

to generate my `.csv` in C# but still one value appears as

```
Code to LSI â€“ END â€“ 11500
```

when the value is returned right to the frontend as

```
Code to LSI – END – 11500
```

It shows wrong only in the `.csv` file.

Note it shows as "Code to LSI ‚Äì END ‚Äì 11500" on another machine

Any idea how can I fix this so it shows "Code to LSI – END – 11500" in the `.csv`?

Comment: the output is [correct in UTF-8](https://www.linestarve.com/tools/mojibake/?mojibake=Code+to+LSI+%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%80%9C+END+%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%80%9C+11500&unescape_html=auto&remove_terminal_escapes=True&fix_encoding=True&restore_byte_a0=True&replace_lossy_sequences=True&decode_inconsistent_utf8=True&fix_c1_controls=True&fix_latin_ligatures=True&fix_character_width=True&uncurl_quotes=True&fix_surrogates=True&remove_control_chars=True&normalization=NFC) but your csv reader reads it in the wrong encoding. You need to tell it that this is UTF-8, or put a BOM at the beginning

Comment: Is that an U+2013 En Dash? Were you expecting a hyphen?

Comment: `System.Web.HttpUtility` <-- This class only exists in .NET Core for back-compat purposes - [you should use `Uri.EscapeDataString` instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring?view=net-7.0).

Comment: `"application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8",` <-- This is not the correct Content-Type for CSV, you should use `text/csv` and only specify the `charset=` parameter if you know _for certain_ what text-encoding is being used...

Comment: What is `bResult` ?

Comment: `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Uri.EscapeDataString(...))` <-- Why are you percent-encoding and then percent-decoding? That entire expression is redundant.